# C++, Matrices, numeros aleatorios?

Tags: c++, funciones

Estoy batallando para hacer un subproceso que llene una matriz de n x n, con números aleatorios pares, los cuales tienen que estar entre 1 y 100.

Según tengo entendido, para generar los números aleatorios puedo usar la función `rand`, pero no domino muy bien lo que son las funciones. No sé cómo empezar. Me gustaría saber si alguien podría ayudarme con el problema.

**Actualizo** / este es el código que he ido avanzando

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    int matriz [12][12];

    for (int fila = 0; fila < 12; fila++)
    {
        for (int columna = 0; columna < 12; columna++)
        {
            matriz[fila][columna] = rand() % 256;

            cout << matriz[fila][columna] << " ";
        }

        cout<<endl;
    }

   cout << "*********************************************************" << endl;

   system("pause");
}
```

ya medio solucione lo de la matriz y de los aleatorios, pero no logro hacer que solo sean pares. Saludos y muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 3):

> no logro hacer que solo sean pares.

Si la limitación es obtener números entre 0 y 100, genera números de 0 a 50 y multiplica por 2 ya que cualquier número multiplicado por dos es par:

```
matriz[fila][columna] = (std::rand() % 50) * 2;
```

> para generar los números aleatorios puedo usar la función rand, pero no domino muy bien lo que son las funciones

Las funciones que generan números [pseudo-aleatorios](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_pseudoaleatorio) tienen varias características que es necesario conocer entre la que la más importante es el tipo de distribución.

La distribución de los resultados de `std::rand` es uniforme<sup>1</sup>, esto significa que cada úno de los números del rango posible tiene exáctamente la misma probabilidad de aparecer que cualquier otro, el rango de los resultados de `std::rand` está entre 0 y 2.147.483.647 (2<sup>31</sup>-1).

Dado el tipo de distribución usada, no se aconseja hacer el módulo del retorno de `std::rand` para generar números aleatorios ya que al usarlo, se aumenta ligeramente la probabilidad de algunos de los números del rango (a no ser que se haga módulo sobre un divisor exácto de 2.147.483.647). En el caso que nos ocupa, los números del 0 al 47 se generarán más veces que los números 48 y 49.

Para evitar eso, es aconsejable usar la librería de números aleatorios de C++11:

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, 49);

int matriz [12][12];

for (int fila = 0; fila < 12; fila++)
{
    for (int columna = 0; columna < 12; columna++)
    {
        matriz[fila][columna] = dis(gen) * 2;

        std::cout << matriz[fila][columna] << ' ';
    }

    std::cout<<'\n';
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Esto puede variar, consulta la documentación de tu compilador.

Answer (score 0):

Debes utilizar un bucle doble, en este caso dos for, para llenar la matriz y un "do while" para la restricción de que sea par

```
 for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<100;j++){
        var aux;
        do{
           aux=rand%100;

           }while(aux%2!=0)

        matriz[i][j]=aux;

    }

 }
```

Comment: Es  más fácil y eficiente generar el número aleatorio incondicionalmente y, si es impar, sumarle uno. Por cierto, `rand() ` es una función. Y tampoco has inicializado la semilla.

Comment: Este algoritmo que propones, tiene ciertos parecidos con el [bogosort](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stupid_sort).