# Extraer el valor mínimo de un arreglo aleatorio de "n" elementos

Tags: c++

Creo tener el código concluido porque al imprimir el programa el valor máximo me lo da bien es correcto el problema esta con el valor mínimo que siempre me da `0` y no sé por qué, alguien podría ayudarme?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

main(){

int n,i,a;

int max=0, min=0;

printf("Numero del arreglo\n");

scanf("%d",&n);

srand(time(NULL));

for(i=0;i<n;i++){

a=0+rand()%((100+0)-0);

printf("%d, ",a);

if(a<min){
    min=a;
}
if(a>max){
    max=a;
}
}
printf("\n\n%d",min);
printf("\n\n%d",max);

getch();

}
```

Comment: `int main()` main() devuelve int

Comment: Aparte de lo comentado por [@Flowen](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/121744/463), no te compliques la vida innecesariamente. Esto: `a=0+rand()%((100+0)-0);` es equivalente a `a = rand()%100;`.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Al comienzo de tu código estableces `min=0`, por lo que no vas a tener ningún número más pequeño:

```
int max=0, min=0;
```

Inicialo a un número alto, por ejemplo:

```
int max=0, min=1000;
```

Comment: Gracias, eso me funciono ya pude hacer que funcionara te lo agradezco, la vdd me falta demaciado apenas soy estudiante y pues se muy poco.
Gracias por tu respuesta

Answer (score 1):

> Extraer el valor mínimo de un arreglo.

¿Arreglo? ¿Qué arreglo? No hay ni un solo arreglo en el código que has compartido.

> El valor mínimo que siempre me da `0` y no sé por qué.

Posiblemente el valor mínimo sea `0`, tu comprobación es:

```
if(a<min){
    min=a;
}
```

Si el valor de `a` es menor que `min` (inicializado a`0`) entonces se iguala `min` a `a`. Dado que generas tus números aleatorios con `rand`:

```
a=0+rand()%((100+0)-0);
```

Y `rand` sólo genera números positivos, no vas a encontrar ningún numero positivo más pequeño que cero.

#### Propuesta.

Asigna el valor máximo al mínimo y el mínimo al máximo:

```
int max=std::numeric_limits<int>::min(), min=std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
```

De esta manera, cualquier número generado (incluido el `0`) por `rand` será menor al valor con el que se inicializa `min`.

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

- Las cabeceras `<stdio.h>`, `<conio.h>`, `<time.h>` y `<stdlib.h>` son de C, no de C++, si realmente necesitas usarlas (que no las necesitas) debes usar los equivalentes de C++: `<cstdio>`, `<iostream>` y `<cstdlib>`. Consulta [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/48268/librerias-de-c-y-c) para saber por qué.
- `printf` y `scanf` son las funciones de lectura de consola de C, en C++ se usan los objetos *stream*: [`std::cout`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout) y [`std::cin`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin).
- Las funciones `rand` y `srand` son herramientas de C no de C++, deberías usar la cabecera [`<random>`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random).

¿Estás seguro de que estabas programando en C++? ¡No lo parece!, por cierto, también te falta devolver un valor en `main`. Y tu generación de números no tiene sentido alguno:

```
a=0+rand()%((100+0)-0);
```

Literalmente suma cero (cero es el [elemento neutro](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elemento_neutro) de la suma) y hace el módulo del resultado de `rand` contra cien sumando cero y restando cero (que es el elemento neutro de la resta), si realmente quieres usar `rand` (que no deberías, consulta [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/30509/c-matrices-numeros-aleatorios/30836#30836) para saber por qué) la formula debería eliminar las operaciones neutras:

```
a=rand()%100;
```

Answer (score 0):

Si vas a hacerlo con C++ deberías utilizar las librerías iostream, vector y algorithms.

Primero llenas un vector con números aleatorios.

```
vector<int> numeros;
for(int i = 0; i < TOTAL_DE_NUMEROS; ++i)
    numeros.push_back(numero aleatorio);
```

Después encuentras el mínimo utilizando la función min_element()

```
int minimo = std::min_element( std::begin(numeros), std::end(numeros) );
std::cout << "El numero más pequeño es: " << minimo << '\n';
```